# Meaning of "been for a sharp walk"

Tags: idioms

A look of secret relief came over their dim faces, for he had towered above them like a statue in silver and bronze [brɒ̱nz]. "Thought maybe you warn't [= wasn't] coming," mumbled Reuben. *"Ah! been for a sharp walk!" he half-shouted. "A sharp walk."*

Comment: Can you please include the source of the quote?

Comment: Also, it seems you're [not the first](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/71594/what-do-they-mean) to be confused by this. Please add more detail!

Comment: BTW "warn't"="weren't", not "wasn't".

Comment: @Catija, nah, Alexey is the one, both times.

Comment: Please don't re-ask a question that has been closed. You should edit the first question with more information.

Comment: @Catija: Meh, let's just leave that one closed instead of duping one to another.

Answer (score 2):

It seems this is a quote from the short story "Time" by H.E. Bates. It can be found, in part, as part of a collection called [*A Day Saved and other modern stories*](https://books.google.com/books?id=28N3CQvBxOIC&pg=PA48&lpg=PA48&dq=Ah!%20been%20for%20a%20sharp%20walk&source=bl&ots=wMrvra8MRc&sig=5NL072ETLfKKKYrUxHLuREUfZ4A&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CDAQ6AEwBGoVChMI8rb0kYDZyAIVUFSICh380Aet#v=onepage&q=Ah!%20been%20for%20a%20sharp%20walk&f=false), in Google Books ed. Peter Taylor.

"Sharp" in this quote is even annotated in the book linked and the meaning is included in a glossary on page 53:

> Sharp : quick

What it doesn't explain is whether quick means "brief" or "quick-paced" but I would guess, from context, that it means [quick](http://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/quick_1) as in brief or short:

> lasting for or taking only a short time

Comment: In modern terms this would be "a short walk".

Comment: see also: "brisk"  ( sharp and stimulating; invigorating: *brisk weather* *brisk walk* )